# Rewrite rules in .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my .htaccess file this piece of code is present:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And I think the code is to tell the website not to include 'index' in the url path. But I also want to tell the website to redirect 'example.com/' to become 'example.com' (without the trailing slash), to avoid duplicate content.

How can I include that rule in the `.htaccess` file? 
And am I able to use the 'IfModule' more than one time?

Thanks

Comment: There isn't a need to include the ifmodule multiple times. You can just add the new code inside the tags.